# Google Analytics user flow not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When trying to open Google Analytics: User flow under Audience I get the following error. I have been seeing it for the last week and not sure what is going wrong.

```
One or more of the services on which we depend is unavailable. Please try again later after the service has had a chance to recover.
```

This feature was working before and I am wondering what went wrong. Thank you. :)

Comment: This is off topic as it's not related to coding and should therefore be closed, but try clearing your cache and cookies and loading the page again. Also, try a different browser. Likely it's a Google issue, but try to rule out other things.

Comment: Thank you sorry if it wasn't on topic should of thought out where to post more

Answer (score 1):

This is a Google-side error. It should clear up with no adjustments on your part, but it's impossible to say how long or what the exact issue is.